# boolean fields in a model are not being updated in the controller when the data is sent

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-core

I had a view without a model in Razor with a form and some inputs and checkboxes, in the controler I'am waiting for a Model to be mapped with the sended data and the input are already well-mapped but the checkboxes not.

I saw the Network Tab in the DevTool and the checkboxes fields are being sent but with an empty data.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditLink(LinkDto editedLinkDto)
{
    // the text fields of editedLinkDto are correctly received, but the booleans (the ckeckboxes) not...
    ...
}
```

The view:

```
...
<form asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="Features" asp-action="EditLink" method="post">
    <input name="LinkName">
    <input name="LinkUrl">

    <input name="BlankTarget" value="true" type="checkbox" />
    <input name="AllowEdit" value="true" type="checkbox" />

    ...
</form>
...
```

PD: The name attributes in the fields has the same name that the attributes of the dto I'm receiving in the dto

As I said before, the LinkName and the LinkUrl fields are being sent but the BlankTarget and AllowEdit fields always are false in the controller and in the DevTool I'm seeing that they are being sent with an empty value.

Comment: Can you put the code for the LinkDto Class

Comment: I’d recommend you to use input tag helpers instead of creating the input elements yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not using `asp-for` attribute , you can modify your codes to add a hidden field. It will be submitted regardless whether the checkbox is checked or not. If the checkbox is checked, the posted value will be `true/false`. The model binder will correctly extract true from the value. Otherwise it will be false :

```
<input type="checkbox" data-val="true" id="BlankTarget" name="BlankTarget" value="true" checked>
<label for="BlankTarget">Name</label>
<input name="BlankTarget" type="hidden" value="false">
```

But it is recommend to use Tag Helpers in asp.net core :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.2